# SSIS - SQL TASK -- Store data in Recordset Destination, then update the data in the Variable Object , is it possible or advisable?

Tags: ssis

**Goal:**  To duplicate the functionality of my stored procedure in SSIS, in memory if possible.

**SP:**  My stored procedure creates a few different temp tables and updates and inserts into those temp tables that get combined into a final temp table used for an insert.

I can just continue to use an SP and an actual table in the DB, but I wanted to see if it was possible or advisable to do these type of things in memory in SSIS?  (Management doesn't want Global Temp tables used.)

The only think I could think of was to store SQL data in a Recordset Destination, and run various updates on that Recordset.  Is this possible in SSIS?

How would you duplicate the functionality described above?

Comment: Can you do all of this in a dataflow? 4 sources with different actions taken on them; combined using merge join and loaded into destination?

Comment: In this case, m SP builds an initial temp table, then everything else happens to that initial temp table.  I don't know how I could do 4 different sources when it's all dependent on the first temp table.  

Thank you for your suggestion @KeithL!